# Selecting select fields in jQuery 1.4 not working

Tags: jquery

This works in jQuery 1.3.2, but not in 1.4

```
$("#container").children().map(function() {
    var child = $(this);

    if (child.is(":select")) {
        //do something with child
    }
});
```

What is the right way to do this in jQuery 1.4?

Comment: Yes, it does not work in 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want select elements:

```
$("#container").children().map(function() {
    var child = $(this);

    if (child.is("select")) {
        //do something with child
    }
});
```

children() does accept a selector, so you can cut this down to:

```
$("#container").children('select').map(function() {
    var child = $(this);
    //do something with child
});
```

Comment: Thanks, still can't believe that : was the big deal :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would suggest accessing the `tagName` (tested):

```
$("#container").children().map(function() {
    var child = $(this);

    if (child[0].tagName == "SELECT") { // or this.tagName == "SELECT"
        //do something with child
    }
});
```